# Golang can't set rpath (Mac)?

Tags: go

Hello currently I tried to set `-rpath` with pkg-config for golang, however I always get the following:

```
ld: -rpath can only be used when creating a dynamic final linked image
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way to fix it?

I tried to use LDFLAGS with -Wl,rpath and I have a pkg-config with -rpath both are failing with the same error.

I also stumbled on github on this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7293
Which means that it should work?

Comment: It might be a silly question, but if you leave out the `-rpath` bit, does it actually produce a dynamically linked executable?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge file says: `backup: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`